# When Testing react component I get an Invalid hook call error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test Login page of my app.It has 2 input field for email and password.  My login page looks like this (part of login page related with error):

```
const Login = (props) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [authStatus, setAuthStatus] = useState(false);

  const onChangeEmail = (e) => {
    const email = e.target.value;
    setEmail(email);
  };

  const onChangePassword = (e) => {
    const password = e.target.value;
    setPassword(password);
  };

  const processResponse = (response) => {
    const currentStatus = response.status;
    const data = response.data;
    return Promise.all([currentStatus, data]).then((res) => ({
      currentStatus: res[0],
      data: res[1],
    }));
  };
.......//some other methods
}
```

Part where ı use t :

```
<div id="user-password-container" className="flex flex-col">
            <label htmlFor="password">{t("text.password")}</label>
            <div className="flex pl-1 items-center space-x-2 w-full h-8 border-2 focus-within:border-primary-900 rounded-lg bg-white">
            </div>
          </div>
```

I wrote some test to test my onChange methods :

```
import React from "react";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { shallow, configure } from "enzyme";
//import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Login from "../login/Login";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
test("message box", () => {});


describe("Login form should be in the document", () => {
  let wrapper;

  test("username check", () => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Login />);

    wrapper.find('input[type="email"]').simulate("change", {
      target: { name: "email", value: "sample.mail@mail.com" },
    });

    expect(wrapper.state("email")).toEqual("sample.mail@mail.com");
  });

  it("password check", () => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Login />);

    wrapper.find('input[type="password"]').simulate("change", {
      target: { name: "password", value: "samplepassword" },
    });

    expect(wrapper.state("password")).toEqual("samplepassword");
  });

});
```

However When I run tests I get an error called Invalid hook calls : [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIz2e.png)

Login form should be in the document › login check with wrong data

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

  11 |
  12 | const Login = (props) => {
> 13 |   const { t } = useTranslation();
     |                 ^
  14 |   const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  15 |   const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  16 |   const [authStatus, setAuthStatus] = useState(false);

  at resolveDispatcher (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1476:13)
  at useContext (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1484:20)
  at useTranslation (node_modules/react-i18next/dist/commonjs/useTranslation.js:28:36)
  at Login (src/app/login/Login.js:13:17)
  at ReactShallowRenderer.render (../../../../node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer-shallow.development.js:829:32)
  at renderElement (../../../../node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:643:26)
  at fn (../../../../node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:707:46)
  at withSetStateAllowed (../../../../node_modules/enzyme-adapter-utils/src/Utils.js:100:18)
  at Object.render (../../../../node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:707:20)
  at new ShallowWrapper (../../../../node_modules/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js:411:22)
  at shallow (../../../../node_modules/enzyme/src/shallow.js:10:10)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/__tests__/Login.test.js:75:15)
```

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Can you include the code in your `Login` functional component where you use actually the `t` variable deconstructed form the `useTranslation` hook? Is it in an event handler or another hook? (This may not have to do with the test itself but how you're using the hook, so it'd be helpful to be sure.)

Comment: Are you missing any context providers for the component under test?

Comment: I added the part that I use t @CatPerry .

Comment: What kind of context provider do you mean ? Can you explain little bit more @DrewReese

Comment: I'm just guessing that the `useTranslation` hook is using some sort of React context value to consume the locale strings it needs to "translate".

Comment: Do you have any solution idea for me to get rid of this error @DrewReese

Comment: Try wrapping the component you are testing with the context provider that is missing. I can see at least a `useContext` hook referenced there in the stacktrace so it seems there is *some* context involved.

Comment: The error is not only for useTranslation. When I delete use translation , it gives same error for useStates below useTranslation line. Can you consider this scenerio? What might be exact problem? @DrewReese

Comment: Hmm, so you probably *aren't* "You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks". By elimination then it seems you are either running more than one instance of React, or maybe your Enzyme adapter doesn't match your regular React version. I see you are using `enzyme-adapter-react-16`, but what version of React is your code using? What if you moved on from Enzyme (*it's practically a deprecated testing paradigm*) and switched to [React-Testing-Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/)?